# Two identical monitors showing different settings in Advanced Display Settings

Tags: windows-10, laptop, graphics-card, windows-11, external-display

I am using a Dell laptop, with a Dell dock, to attached two Dell Monitors (U5252D). I am hoping to replace my older Dell U2419H. Both connected though display port cables to the Dell dock.

When I add the new monitor one at a time (laptop screen and monitor) it looks great. When I add the second display (2 monitors + laptop) that new monitor has a slit jitter/ shimmy/ dance. Most noticeably on text. Looking though the advanced display I assume this has something to do with the interlaced refresh rate.

Laptop is a Dell Latitude 5591 with i7, but reproducible on another model.

Why is the model and driver identified correctly, but not offering the same resolution and refresh rate?
What can be done to get both displays to look acceptable?
This is a non gaming/ graphics intensive setup.

[image: Display 2 showing 2560 x 1440, 59.95Hz]
[image: Display 3 showing 2048 x 1080, 59.94iHz]

Update 1 2022/06/30
I tried another dock I had "Dell TB16" and the issue wasn't present. It was present when I used the "Dell WD19TB". This was unexpected as the WD19TB is newer and the tech specs look for capable.

Comment: Try updating BIOS (UEFI), Chipset, and Video drivers.

Comment: What graphics card do you have? This appears to be utilizing the on board graphics of your Intel processor, rather than the GPU itself.

Comment: Dell command update does not have any missing/pending updates. Device manager says I should have Intel UHD Graphics 630 and a NVIDIA GeForce MX130.

Answer (score 0):

After some back and forth with Dell support, it looks like there is some compatibility issues with some laptops and some monitors. Then the laptop is not on a fully compatible dock the displays may have issues.
:(